# Firebase authentication with React

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can anyone help with this code? I am trying to do a website project with React and firebase authentication. When I try to run the code, React shows an error => Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { auth, provider, storage };
export default db;
```

I have tried multiple times of changing the import statement but its not working

Comment: What version of the Firebase SDKs are you running. For v9 and above, have a look at  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup and https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade. For the simplest upgrade, consider the `compat` llibraries described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_compat_libraries

Answer (score 2):

Try this if it's before version 8:
`import firebase from 'firebase/app';`
as your Firebase Import.

Version 9 and above:
`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`